# Bind to Uri in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am binding a list of urls to a ListBox (MVVM) and found that if the model is a `string[]` everything works fine but if it's a `List<Uri>` then no items are displayed in my `ListBox`.  I assume this is because WPF doesn't know how to convert a `Uri` into a `string` but

1. I'd figure it would just call `ToString()` which is what I want
2. I don't know how to *tell* WPF how to do the right thing

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UrlsFound, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="String">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now as long as `UrlsFound` is a `string[]` the binding works, but if I refactor to make it a `List<Uri>` nothing is displayed in the ListBox.  I changed the `DataType="String"` to `"Uri"` but that didn't help

Comment: What about removing `DataType` altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something else wrong as I've copied your XAML and it works.

Here's my code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 public MainWindow()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  urlsFound.Add(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
  urlsFound.Add(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
  urlsFound.Add(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
  this.DataContext = this;

 }

 private List<Uri> urlsFound=new List<Uri>();
 public List<Uri> UrlsFound
 {
  get { return urlsFound; }
  set { urlsFound = value; }
 }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I think this has to do with my XAML theme.